# How to pass relative path to use the File.Delete static function in C#?

Tags: c#

I've been trying to create a way to upload, download and delete a PDF file. The upload and the download function work fine, but when I try to delete the PDF it doesn't really work as I want it to.

It does work when I use this form:

`File.Delete(@"C:\Users\Donovan\1_Test.pdf");`

But it doesn't work when I try this:

`File.Delete(@"~\1_Test.pdf");`

I want to find a way to make the second line of code work, because I work in a team and we don't share the same file path.

Comment: `~` does not work on windows. You should use the `Environment` class to access home directory: `Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal`

Comment: That look linux-ish. Try Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile); to get the users root folder.

Comment: You mention upload and download. Are you trying to delete remote server file from outside the server?

Comment: Are you writing an ASP application of some sort? If so, it sounds like you're looking for something like `MapPath` but what you need specifically will depend on *exactly what sort of asp application you're writing* (since "classic" ASP.Net has such a function in `System.Web` but newer ASP.Net applications no longer have that dependency)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever MapPath always maps to the folder of the application running(i.e. D:/Inetput/wwwroot/MyApplication), I hope he's saving his files in a seperate directory.

Comment: @Chriz - yes, but if they're already working with paths of the form `~\1_Test.pdf` that would be my best guess for what they're doing. So if the OP can clarify that this is the case, we can point them at the appropriate function *and* warn that they almost certainly shouldn't be placing user supplied files in the root of their application. Absent that, no idea how they'd end up with a path that looks like that.

Comment: Your question is not clear. You need to define what exactly you are trying to find a path relative to. You want it relative to a fixed path, a config path, the application. Also, what type of application are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. I think it works :D

```
File.Delete(Server.MapPath("~/") + "1_Test.pdf");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Environment.GetFolderPath` to find the user's home directory.

```
string home = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UseProfile);
File.Delete(Path.Combine(home, "1_Test.pdf"));
```

You might also want to consider putting the file in the folder for temporary files instead. You can find that location with `Path.GetTempPath`. (Note that windows will not automatically clean up temporary files, so you still need to delete anything you put there after you are done with it.)

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. But when I give this code to my teammate I'm afraid that this won't work for them, since they don't have this project in the same folder.

Comment: I think based on comments that it is clear that the OP want the path relative to the application, and not specifically the user profile path... so this answer is not correct. I will hold off on downvote for now if you want to fix it. Though I am not sure there is enough info from the OP to post a good answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are all using the userpath you can go with this approach:

```
System.IO.File.Delete(
    Path.Combine(
         Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile), 
         "1_Test.pdf"
    )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

You unfortunately cannot make it work with `~`. This only works as a relative path for web applications.

We use a local config file for our application where each developer stores its own preferences and can change these independent of other developers.

Depending on your application (web, desktop, mobile, windows, linux, whatever) you can write a config-object and fill it or use i.e. appsettings in web.config for this purpose.

```
var basePath = Config.FileBase;
File.Delete(Path.Combine(basePath, "\1_Test.pdf"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Another method:

```
File.Delete(Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%USERPROFILE%\\1_Test.pdf"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered it to put the *.pdf files in a database?

Comment: I have considered it, but I decided to try it this way :)